# Roots of Quadratic Equation and its nature?

Tags: quadratics

For what value of **k** will **3x^2 + 5x + k = 0** have Equal roots?

For Equal roots discriminant should be equal to zero. So what would be the value of k?

Comment: "For Equal roots discriminant should be equal to zero. " Ok good. And then...?

Comment: The discriminant is $b^2-4ac$. What are $a$, $b$ and $c$ here?

Comment: You have the quadratic equation and you know that discriminant should be equal to zero. So the question is now, what is the discriminant?

Answer (score 1):

$$D=b^2-4ac=25-12k$$ now 
$D=0$ if and only if $k=\frac{25}{12}$.

Comment: Thank you Rene Schipperus.

Comment: My pleasure....